# Overloaded constructor usage

Tags: java

I am using the below syntax to get the error code from ErrorCodeEnum class. How can I do this directly using an overloaded constructor in ErrorCodeEnum class?

`new ServiceException(ErrorCodeEnum.ERROR_1005.getErrorCode() )`

Create an overloaded constructor taking error code directly.

I have classes as below 
public class MainException extends RuntimeException {

```
private String errorMessage;

private ErrorCodeEnum errorCodeEnum;


public MainException() {

}



public MainException (ErrorCodeEnum errorCodeEnum, String errorMessage) {
    //super(errorMessage);
    this.errorCodeEnum = errorCodeEnum;
    this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
}

public String getErrorCode() {
    return errorCode;
}



public String getErrorMessage() {
    return errorMessage;
}
```

}

and base class as :
public class ServiceException extends MainException {

```
public ServiceException() {
}


public ServiceException(ErrorCodeEnum errorCodeEnum,String errorMessage) {

    super(errorCodeEnum,errorMessage);

}
```

}

not able to overload it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to ServiceException to accept an instance of ErrorCodeEnum directly?

What I'm guessing you have now:

```
public class ServiceException {

    public ServiceException(int errorCode) {
        // do stuff
    }

}
```

To simply overload the constructor, you can do it like this:

```
public class ServiceException {

    public ServiceException(int errorCode) {
        // do stuff
    }

    public ServiceException(ErrorCodeEnum errorCodeEnum) {
        // do other stuff
    }

}
```

You can then call `new ServiceException(ErrorCodeEnum.ERROR_1005)` directly. As for the implementation of the new constructor, the easiest way would probably be to utilize the existing constructor and pass it the error code, which you can call with a reference to `this`:

```
public class ServiceException {

    public ServiceException(int errorCode) {
        // do stuff
    }

    public ServiceException(ErrorCodeEnum errorCodeEnum) {
        this(errorCodeEnum.getErrorCode());
    }

}
```

Comment: I have something like this ---throw new ServiceException(
ErrorCodeEnum.ERROR_1001.getErrorCode(),"Invalid data ");

Comment: how should i define string param in constructor along with ErrorCodeEnum ?

Comment: `public ServiceException(ErrorCodeEnum errorCodeEnum, String message) {this(errorCodeEnum.getErrorCode(), message);}` This is really basic Java stuff. Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/index.html

Comment: @ JB Nizet ,i have edited the question with my exception classes

Answer (score 1):

The constructor of ErrorCodeEnum can't return you a ServiceException. What you can do is to define a constructor of ServiceException which takes an instance of the enum itself:

```
public ServiceException(ErrorCodeEnum e) {
    this(e.getErrorCode());
}
```

and thus be able to use

```
throw new ServiceException(ErrorCodeEnum.ERROR_1005);
```

Or a method in the enum which returns a ServiceException:

```
public enum ErrorCodeEnum {

    // ...

    public newServiceException() {
        return new ServiceException(this.getErrorCode());
    }
}
```

and thus be able to use

```
throw ErrorCodeEnum.ERROR_1005.newServiceException();
```

You may of course do both.

Comment: I have MainException class extended by ServiceException,so this overloaded constructer can be written in MainException class?